# Elasticsearch scroll previous like API

Tags: elasticsearch, scroll, pagination

I have continuously generating time series data which I am putting in elasticsearch. One of the requirement is to get records with pagination. However I want the records of that time when the query was made even on next page.

From & Size API or search_after APIs of elasticsearch don't maintain snapshot and return latest data.
Scroll API does not have way to go back.

How can I fulfill my requirement, pagination without new data and option to go next and previous?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the use case exactly - are users going to use the first pages and that's it, or are you planning to scan the entire response data set?

if you wish to explore and scan through all the data or a large amount of pages then you would need to use the Scroll API, as paging mechanism is not that robust to traverse large data sets (in default it break at around 10000).

Indeed the scroll doesn't support 'page back', but it is a matter of usage need. Do you plan to just scan through all the data, or provide simple paging where you expect people to click 'page back'? if the case is humans looking at pages then I don't think that the paging size limitations would be reached, and you better off using Paging and not scroll.

If you would choose paging, in order to have 'pagination without new data' you can add time range filter to the query, with fix from & to timestamps. so that the result should be consistent (instead of using now())